# Can we add appenders to lombok @Log4j via xml

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, log4j2, slf4j, lombok

Hi I have a scenario like this, I got a Spring boot project from a client, they have used `Lombok` for  logging using `@Slf4j` annotation my task is to pass logs to `Elasticsearch` without using any collectors (aka Logstash , Fluentd ,etc.) so I looked in a project called [Log4j2-Elasticsearch](https://github.com/rfoltyns/log4j2-elasticsearch) In that They have used appenders like this in `.xml` file

```
<Appenders>
    <Elasticsearch name="elasticsearchAsyncBatch">
        <IndexName indexName="log4j2" />
        <JacksonJsonLayout />
        <AsyncBatchDelivery>
            <IndexTemplate name="log4j2" path="classpath:indexTemplate.json" />
            <JestHttp serverUris="http://localhost:9200" />
        </AsyncBatchDelivery>
    </Elasticsearch>
</Appenders>
```

In my project They have used `Lombok` can we add appenders to Lombok `@Slf4j` if it is so How ?

Comment: slf4j is just a facade, use Log4j2 as an implementation and you can use this appender.

Answer (score 1):

No. All Lombok is doing is saving you from making a getLogger call. You still have to make the logging calls and provide the configuration.